# How to properly hash a password

Tags: c#, md5

I want to re-create the MyBB hashing process so I can use its database to authenticate users on a 3rd party app (written on C#).

MyBB uses:

`md5(md5($salt).password)`

My problem is that the result I get on C# is nowhere similar to the one MyBB gets.

What I've done on C#:

```
public string HashPass(string password, string salt)
{
    MD5 md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();

    byte[] saltHash =md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt));

    string passwordAndSalt = password + System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(saltHash);

    byte[] finalHash = md5.ComputeHash(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(passwordAndSalt));

    string final = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(finalHash);
    return final;
}
```

The result I get from using that function for password "Test123" and salt "0fYR6mEE" (gathered from MyBB db) is: "??R?????s??" while the actual result should look like "VaHffsyzJeEa4dB3bbMWeUlJObAfN5I9rf1CuNRXCa6xPJTzXL".

Most likely I'm missing something obvious, sorry about that.

Comment: How do you know MyBB uses ASCII to get the data and to get the result?

Comment: `MD5` is junk, don't use it. Look into other algorithms like bcrypt, scrypt and or sha512crypt for at least passwords

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ That comment isn't useful, did you read the question? "I want to re-create the MyBB hashing process so I can use its database to authenticate users". Don't assume the OP can use whatever they want

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I agree it's not useful per say the issue the OP is having, then again it's only a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: Pure guessing and from some examples i've seen around. @CamiloTerevinto

Comment: The expected result looks like a base64 encrypted string created from the bytes. `string final = System.Convert.ToBase64String(finalHash);`. You cannot encode it as ASCII, as the bytes contain invalid or at least unreadable ASCII codes.

Comment: So whats the way to get "VaHffsyzJeEa4dB3bbMWeUlJObAfN5I9rf1CuNRXCa6xPJTzXL" from "Test123" + "0fYR6mEE"? @OlivierJacot-Descombes

Answer (score 0):

There are unknowns here. Which encoding does MyBB use to the password bytes? It could be ASCII, ANSI, or UTF8 or it could get the string bytes directly, i.e., without encoding. So I will write it partly as pseudo code

```
byte[] passwordBytes = GetBytes(password); // Where you have to define GetBytes
byte[] saltBytes = System.Convert.FromBase64String(salt); // Assuming it is given as base64

// Merge the password bytes and the salt bytes
var mergedBytes = new byte[passwordBytes.Length + saltBytes.Length];
Array.Copy(passwordBytes, mergedBytes, passwordBytes.Length);
Array.Copy(saltBytes, 0, mergedBytes, passwordBytes.Length, saltBytes.Length);

var md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
byte[] finalHash = md5.ComputeHash(mergedBytes);
string final = System.Convert.ToBase64String(finalHash);
```

Note that I'm merging the password bytes and the salt bytes, not the password string and the salt string. Then the MD5 it taken only once from these merged bytes.

But I'm not sure what `md5(md5($salt).password)` does. Is `md5()` returning the the hash as base64 string already? Maybe you would have to convert the salt from base64 to `bytes[]`, then get the MD% hash, convert it into a base64 string and then concatenate it with the password string. Then get the bytes from this combined string, do the hash again and convert the result to a base64 string again.

You would have to dig deeper into the source code of MyBB to be sure.

Comment: md5() is the default function used in PHP. http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1321.html
I think it uses a custom encoding system, if so, idk how to implement it on c#
@Oliver Jacot-Descombes

Comment: `md5($salt).password` seems to be a concatenation (I don't know this language. Is it PHP?). But a concatenation of what? If `md5()` yields bytes and `password` is a string, what does it do? Does it magically convert the bytes into string or convert the string into bytes? Are the string characters 1 or 2 bytes. A better understanding of the [original code](https://github.com/mybb) would be required to answer all these questions.